# Consulta NODEJS MYSQL Si registro existe en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

soy nuevo en NodeJS

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de parqueadero, deseo registrar la entrada de un vehiculo para lo cual solamente debo ingresar la placa del vehiculo, si esta placa ya está registrada en la tabla vehiculos me debe permitir llenar la tabla entrada_vehiculos, he creado la relación entre las dos tablas a través de una llave foranea en la tabla entrada_vehiculos referenciando al campo vehiculos_id

Este es el código que he construido

```
 router.post('/add', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    //Recoge los datos del formulario y guarda en un objeto nuevo
    const {license_plate_entrada, novedades} = req.body;
       
    let nuevoEntrada = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM vehiculos WHERE license_plate = ?', [license_plate_entrada]);
    //El objeto nuevo se llama newLink
    const newLink = {
        license_plate_entrada,
        novedades,
        id_vehiculo_entrada: nuevoEntrada.vehiculos_id
    };  
    if(nuevoEntrada.length > 0){
        console.log(nuevoEntrada);
        
        await pool.query('INSERT into entrada_vehiculo set ?', [newLink]);
        req.flash('success', 'Entrada registrada correctamente');
        res.redirect('/entrance');
    }else{
        req.flash('success', 'El vehículo no existe');
        res.redirect('/entrance');
    }
    
});
```

Me arroja este error:

```
  code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlMessage: "Column 'id_vehiculo_entrada' cannot be null",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT into entrada_vehiculo set `license_plate_entrada` = 'AX205', `novedades` = 'a', `id_vehiculo_entrada` = NULL"
```

Comment: El `pool.query` retorna un response que mayormente que se recibe en un `.then()` y se trabaja así `res.rows[0].propiedad`; en este caso tu propiedad sería vehiculos_id

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera, gracias a lsanchezo por su comentario.

```
router.post('/add', isLoggedIn, async (req, res) => {
    //Recoge los datos del formulario y guarda en un objeto nuevo
    const {license_plate_entrada, novedades} = req.body;
    const nuevoEntrada = await pool.query('SELECT vehiculos_id FROM vehiculos WHERE license_plate = ?', [license_plate_entrada]);
    //El objeto nuevo se llama newLink
    const newLink = null;
    console.log(newLink);
    console.log(nuevoEntrada);
    if(nuevoEntrada.length > 0){
        const newLink = {
            license_plate_entrada,
            novedades,
            id_vehiculo_entrada: nuevoEntrada[0].vehiculos_id
        };  
        pool.query('INSERT INTO entrada_vehiculo set ?', [newLink]);
        req.flash('success', 'Entrada registrada correctamente');
        res.redirect('/entrance');
    }else{
        req.flash('success', 'El vehículo no existe');
        res.redirect('/entrance');

    }
    
});
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).